# I do not know why pointers are used differently for functions

Tags: c

I don't know the concept of the pointer so I ask.
I do not know why pointers are used differently for functions.

```
int is_full(StackType *s)
{
    return (s->top == (MAX_STACK_SIZE -1)); 
}
```

```
void push(StackType *s, element item)
{
    if (is_full(s)) {
        fprintf(stderr, "error\n");
        return;
    }
    else {
        s->data[++(s->top)] = item;
    }   
}
```

```
int main()
{
    StackType s;

    init_stack(&s);
    push(&s, 1);
    push(&s, 2);
    push(&s, 3);

    printf("%d\n", pop(&s));
    printf("%d\n", pop(&s));
    printf("%d\n", pop(&s));
}
```

In first function,I set `is_full(StackType *s)`
In second function,I set `push(StackType*s, element item)`

Second function calls `if (is_full(s))`
Main calls `push(&s, 1)`

It's the same function but why is it different to call?

Comment: In `push`, `s` is already a pointer. In `main` it is an object (struct).

Answer (score 4):

The type of variable `s` in function `main` is `StackType`.

The type of variable `s` in function `is_full` is `StackType*`.

Comment: Ohh... Thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

While goodvibration is correct in his answer, it is also important to know that what you are passing with `&` is an address to StackType, which is the held within `*s` - a pointer variable holding the address passed to it, thus enabling operations on memory (e.g the ones done in the `else` case)